# Delete a google classroom class with an Unknown user

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I am trying to delete an archived class but it gives me an error. The class has an user, but when I enter in the class, any student is not displayed.
I have made an request to the API and the result is that an user exists in class.

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/365060561/students?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

 "students": [
  {
   "courseId": "365060561",
   "userId": "112081802784063363282",
   "profile": {
    "id": "112081802784063363282",
    "name": {
     "fullName": "Unknown user"
    },
   }
  }
 ]
```

But if I seek the information about this user, the result is that it not exists.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/112081802784063363282?key={YOUR_API_KEY}



"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Resource Not Found: userKey"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Resource Not Found: userKey"
 }
```

How can I delete this class?

Thank you.

Comment: What error do you see when attempting to delete the class? Does deleting the class work from the admin console?

Comment: I try to delete the course with id: 365060561. In https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/delete?authuser=1#try-it. The result is:   `"error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal error encountered.",
  "status": "INTERNAL"
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a clarification.

You get the unknown user in the api when the user has been deleted. This doesn't seem to be cascaded down to Classroom.

Unfortunately you can't remove the user from the class using the api as you get

> ```
> {
>   "error": {
>     "code": 404,
>     "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
>     "status": "NOT_FOUND"
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You must always specify the full name/full email address of the user or else the Google unique id of the user. It's not sufficient to simply provide the local part of the username as this does not allow Google to determine which [Google Apps domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en) the user is associated with. As shown in the [service account documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), service accounts are not themselves domain admins, so they need to impersonate one in order to use the Admin SDK APIs.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.